# Java - Specific validation error

Tags: java, coding-style

I want to validate a class called `Person`. I could write something like:

```
class Person {
  ...
  public boolean isValid() {
    return (name != null && age > 0);
  }
}
```

However, in my presentation layer, I want to show the user the specific reason for why the validation failed.

The solutions I've come up with are:

1. Throw exceptions within `isValid()` specific to the error
2. Make `isValid()` return a `PersonValidationError` enum instead of a boolean
3. Duplicate the validation logic in the presentation layer

I want to know what the best way of handling this is. Also, how does the Java standard library deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: This is more of a code review thing, but I'd suggest making `Person` an `interface` that is therefore a contract. At that point, you can provide some implementation of `Person` that fails upon construction with an exception that provides a resource's name. That resource name could then be localized and used by the presentation layer to load (and theoretically the exception could also provide values with it like a `MessageFormat`). _Or_ provide some separate validator that itself throws similar exceptions. You will need to validate input either way, which can give closer, more accurate errors.

Answer (score 3):

A few point before presenting my solution:

1. Exceptions should be used for more or less *exceptional* conditions.
   From what you say it would be not uncommon for the users to submit
   wrong data.
2. When your `Person` class grows, you will be adding more and more conditions that must be met for it      to be valid.
3. With exceptions you can display only one error at a time, what if more than one thing is wrong with the submitted data?
4. Putting validation method to your `Person` class doesn't seem right. For example, what if you wanted to have different validation policies in different places in you app?

So, I would leave your Person class free from validation logic:

```
class Person {

    final String name;
    final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And then implement some class that takes a person and validates it. The idea is to have different validators, each with its own validation rule and own validation message. `enum` is great to achieve that:

```
enum Validator {

    NOT_NULL_NAME("Name must not be null") {
        @Override
        public boolean validate(Person person) {
            return person.name != null;
        }
    },
    AGE_GREATER_THAN_ZERO("Age must be greater than zero") {
        @Override
        public boolean validate(Person person) {
            return person.age > 0;
        }
    };

    final String errorMessage;

    private Validator(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public abstract boolean validate(Person person);
}
```

See how easy would be to add some new condition with a different message? Just another enum instance.

And now create a class for validating persons. It just loops over all validators and gathers error messages.

```
class PersonValidator {

    private final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    public PersonValidator(Person person) {
        for (Validator validator : Validator.values()) {
            if (!validator.validate(person)) {
                errors.add(validator.errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return errors.isEmpty();
    }

    public Collection<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Example of how to use it:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Person[] people = { new Person(null, 0), 
                         new Person(null, 42), 
                         new Person("Joe", 0), 
                         new Person("Joe", 42) };
    for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        PersonValidator validator = new PersonValidator(people[i]);
        System.out.println(String.format("Person no %s is %s valid. %s", 
              i, 
              validator.isValid() ? "" : "not", 
              Joiner.on(", ").join(validator.getErrors())));

    }
}
```

The above prints:

```
Person no 0 is not valid. Name must not be null, Age must be greater than zero
Person no 1 is not valid. Name must not be null
Person no 2 is not valid. Age must be greater than zero
Person no 3 is  valid.
```

Pretty neat, huh?

Comment: Nice & elegant java native solution^

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are using. I'm used to Spring MVC projects.
On these, you can use JSR-303 validators, which will fill an ObjectErros object with all the errors on the object.

If you are using spring, try looking for SmartValidator. After injecting it, you can do:

```
BeanPropertyErrors br = new BeanPropertyErros();
validator.validate(object,br);
```

If you're not using Spring, try to look for JSR-303 implementations.

With it you can use @NotEmpty, @NotNull, @Min, @Length on the fields of the class to be validated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Throwing exception from bool function is not a good way
2. What it returns if name is null and age is <0?
3. Sometimes can be a solution, but not in this case

I propose something like:

```
class Person {
...
private boolean isValidated = false;
private ArrayList<String> validationErrors = new ArrayList<String>();
private void validate()
{
    validationErrors.clear();
    if (name == null)
        validationErrors.add("Incorrect name");
    if (age < 0)
        validationErrors.add("Incorrect age");
    isValidated = true;
}
public boolean isValid()
{
    if (!isValidated)
        validate();
    return (validationErrors.size()==0);
}
public ArrayList<String> getValidationErors()
{
    if (!isValidated)
        validate();
    return validationErrors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have settled on the following solution for now:

```
class Person {
  ...
  public void validate() throws ValidationException {
    if(name == null) {
      throw ValidationException("Name cannot be null");
    }

    if(age < 0) {
      throw ValidationException("Age cannot be less than 0");
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my presentation layer I can do the following:

```
try {
  myPerson.validate();
} catch(ValidationException e) {
  errorMessage = "Invalid person: " + e.getMessage();
}
```